# How to select size of json array in postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I've been fighting this for a long time, but I am not able to construct a query, which would select (and preferably also order by) a count of items in an array.

I do have table data like this:

```
ID    Data
1     {"$id": "1", "InnerArray": [{"$id": "1", "Timestamp": "2020-06-18T09:43:19.4873323+01:00"}, {"$id": "3", "Timestamp": "2020-06-19T08:25:35.7768657+00:00"}]}
etc...
```

And what did I try...

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH("Data" ->'InnerArray'::json) AS lengtha
FROM "mystorage"
```

also

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH("Data"::json ->'InnerArray'::json) AS lengtha
```

But it sais

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "InnerArray" is invalid.
  Position: 49
  Where: JSON data, line 1: InnerArray
```

I've tried a lot of different formats but coming from the MS SQL world, my understanding of PostgreSQL seems a bit limited.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, thank you, however I am probably not going to rewrite existing product with hundreds of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand parameter for the `->` operator should be a `text` value, not a `json` value. So the cast `'InnerArray'::json` is not needed to begin with.

But it's also the reason for your error, because `'InnerArray'` isn't a valid JSON value, so you can't cast it to one.

Use:

```
SELECT json_array_length("Data"::json -> 'InnerArray') AS lengtha
```

Btw: if you do store JSON values, your column should be defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`), rather than using `text` (or `varchar`)  and casting it everytime you want to use a JSON function.

Comment: Wow, I thought I tried that one a thousand times.Also, I have my data stored as json datatype, but it's defined by 3rd party product, so not much what I can change anyways. Thanks.

Comment: @JiříHerník: if the column is defined as `json` you can get rid of the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a }.  Try this:

`select json_array_length('{"$id": "1", "InnerArray": [{"$id": "1", "Timestamp": "2020-06-18T09:43:19.4873323+01:00"}, {"$id": "3", "Timestamp": "2020-06-19T08:25:35.7768657+00:00"}]}'::json->'InnerArray') as lengtha`

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, but the point is, that I need to select it from DB field, not inline.